# Solving the ODE $yy'y'' = f(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to solve or at least know the existence of a solution to $yy'y'' = f(x)$.

This was a question posted to my local math forum, and there was no context given to it, but obviously, it would certainly depend on the condition on $f$, so I am going to assume $f$ is continuously differentiable.

**My work:**

If I could write it in the form $y'=something$, then we might be able to apply the existence theorem, so I tried to write it in the form.

Similar question [Solve ODE $yy'y''=(y')^3+(y'')^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3807022/solve-ode-yyy-y3y2) uses the substitution $y'=u$, so I applied it in this case, and I will get the following equation: $yu^2 u' = f(x)$.

Now if $y\neq 0$ and $u=y'\neq 0$, we can say $u'= \frac{f(x)}{yu^2}$... and now what can we do? Can we apply the existence theorem now? If so how?

Comment: The substitution trick $y'=u(y)$ only works for autonomous equations, transforming them into a non-autonomous one of one order less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

$$\begin{cases}
z_1= y\\
z_2 = y^\prime
\end{cases}$$ The given equation is equivalent to

$$Z^\prime(x)=F(x,Z(x))$$ where

$$Z(x)=\begin{pmatrix}
z_1(x)\\
z_2(x)\end{pmatrix}, \,
F(x,Z)=\begin{pmatrix}
z_2\\
\frac{f(x)}{z_1 z_2}\end{pmatrix}$$ If $y_(x_0)\neq 0$ and $y^\prime(x_0)\neq 0$, you can apply Picard-Lindelöf theorem around $x_0$ to get a unique solution to the IVP in a neighborhood of $x_0$ as $F$ is locally Lipschitz  in $Z$. According to this theorem, the continuity of $f$ is sufficient to ensure existence and unicity.